# Materials with "closest" interpolation show up unsaturated in material preview shading

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm trying to render a minecraft scene in blender, but when I switch the texture interpolation to "Closest", it shows up unsaturated in the viewport (with material preview).
This doesn't affect the rendered output at all, but it makes the preview look bad, and makes it harder to differenciate between textures.

[image: Image with Linear interpolation]
[image: Image with Closest interpolation]